# How can I play a .wav file from a song with a numpy array and make it sound good?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, audio, wav

I have a 17 second .wav file which is a specific part near the end of the song Feeling Good by Michael Bublé. My code does the direct and inverse Fourier transform of the numpy array obtained from the song, and then shows the graph in time, in frequency, and plays the song. Then it applies a low-pass filter so frequencies below 1000Hz are blocked, and shows the same plots again, and replays the filtered song, showing the difference. However both audios are played with a lot of noise and it sounds awful. Below is my whole code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile
import sounddevice as sd    

# Load audio file
fs, x_t = wavfile.read('song.wav')
# If audio has only one channel, divide the signal by 2; otherwise, leave it as is
if x_t.ndim == 2:
    x_t = 0.5 * (x_t[:, 0] + x_t[:, 1])

n = len(x_t)
tiempo = n / fs  # Duration of the audio
Delta_t = 1 / fs  # Sampling time
x_t = x_t/np.max(np.abs(x_t))

# Plot time-domain representation of the audio
t = np.arange(0, n) * Delta_t
plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t, x_t)


# Compute and plot the spectrum
X_w = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(x_t))
Delta_f = 1 / (n * Delta_t)
f = np.arange(-n/2, n/2) * Delta_f
DE_X_w = np.abs(X_w)
plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
plt.plot(f, DE_X_w / np.max(DE_X_w))

# Inverse transform and plot
x_t_inv = np.fft.ifft(np.fft.ifftshift(X_w))
x_t_2 = np.real(x_t_inv)
plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
plt.plot(t, x_t_2)

print(max(x_t))
print(min(x_t))


print(max(x_t_2))
print(min(x_t_2))


scaled = np.int16(x_t_2 / np.max(np.abs(x_t_2)) * 32767)
#sd.play(scaled, fs)
"""
sd.play(x_t, fs)  # Convert to 16-bit integer format
sd.wait()
sd.play(x_t_2, fs)  # Convert to 16-bit integer format
sd.wait()
"""
sd.play(scaled, fs)  # Convert to 16-bit integer format
sd.wait()

# Low-pass filter
fpb = 1 * (np.abs(f) <= 1000)

# Plot the low-pass filter
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.plot(f, fpb)

# Apply the filter in the frequency domain
X_w_fil = X_w * fpb
plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
plt.plot(f, np.abs(X_w_fil) / np.max(np.abs(X_w_fil)))

# Inverse transform and plot the filtered signal in the time domain
x_t_filt = np.fft.ifft(np.fft.ifftshift(X_w_fil))
x_t_filt = np.real(x_t_filt)
plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
plt.plot(t, x_t_filt)

# Play the filtered audio
#sd.play((np.around(x_t_filt)).astype(np.int16), fs)  # Convert to 16-bit integer format
#sd.wait()


plt.show()
```

I have tried playing it as is (float32), I have tried dividing the array by its maximum, I have tried converting it into a int16 array multiplying by 32767, converting the array into its absolute value, and none of these have worked. Some have made it more audible but it still plays with a lot of noise. The filtered though somehow plays almost perfectly. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Check `x_t.dtype`, the problem is likely that it is an integer type and you are overflowing in this operation `0.5 * (x_t[:, 0] + x_t[:, 1])`

Comment: What would be more appropriate is `x_t = (x_t[:, 0] // 2) + (x_t[:, 1] // 2)`

Comment: or `x_t = (x_t // x_t.ndim).sum(1)`

Comment: Have you tried avoiding the fft/ifft step by using a high-pass filter? Example here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html